# How to Load Twig Template Outside of the Theme Folder?

Tags: php, templates, twig

I just learning Twig templating and I am having trouble figuring out how to load a template part that is in a directory outside of the current themes' directory so they can be reused by other themes.

I am starting with just a simple loading of a head.html template part located in the core/tpls/ directory. With the variouse methodes I have tried, I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message
>   'Unable to find template "/home/ubuntu/workspace/core/tpls/head.html"
>   (looked into: /home/ubuntu/workspace/themes/core) in "base.html" at
>   line 5.

The file is in the directory and the path is correct despite that the log error says otherwise.

My base.html located in the themes/core/ directory contains the custom Twig function to include the head.html template located outside of the theme directory:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>

    {% include core.head %} // This is line 5 and throws the error and need to work correctly
    // {% include core_head %} // This throws the error and should function the same as {% include core_head %}
    // {% include tpl.head %} <-- If I use this, my function for grabbing templates from the theme works since I have a copy of the head.html in the theme dir too //

</head>
<body>

<header id="header">

    {% include tpl.header %} // This works via the get_tpl() function

</header>

    {% include tpl.breadcrumbs %} // This works too

[. . .]
```

I hate to clutter this with an entire class but it may be helpful for someone to see what I have wrong.  The get_core_tpl() function is what I cannot get working where my other get_*() functions work as they should.  See my comments there and also, take note to my comments in the befor_rendor() function:

```
<?php

class Get_TPLs {

    private $tpl_name,
            $theme = 'core',
            $tpl_array = array(
                'breadcrumbs',
                'content',
                'cover',
                'footer',
                'head',
                'header',
                'sidebar'
    );

    public function before_load_content(&$file) {
        $this->tpl_name = basename($file, '.md');
    }

    public function config_loaded(&$settings) {

        if (isset($settings['core_tpl']))
            $this->core_tpl = $settings['core_tpl'];

        if (isset($settings['tpl_array']))
            $this->tpl_array = $settings['tpl_array'];

        if (isset($settings['theme']))
            $this->theme = THEMES_DIR . $settings['theme'];
    }

    public function file_meta(&$meta) {

        $config = $meta;
        if (isset($config['slug'])):
            $this->tpl_name = strtolower($config['slug']);
        endif;
    }

    public function before_render(&$twig_vars, &$twig) {

 //// ==== THIS IS CALLED WITH {% include core.[TEMPLATE_NAME] %} SEE Base.html ==== ////

        // core/tpl/file
        $twig_vars['core'] = $this->get_core_tpl();

//// === THIS IS A SIMPLIFIED VERSION OF THE ABOVE VAR - IT'S CALLED WITH {% include core_head %} but It throws the same error ==== ////

        $twig_vars['core_head'] = CORE_TPL . '/head.html';

        // theme/tpl/file
        $twig_vars['tpl'] = $this->get_tpl();

        // theme/tpl/views/file
        $views = $this->get_views();
        $twig_vars['views'] = $views;

        // theme/content/file
        $theme = $this->get_theme_content();
        $twig_vars['theme'] = $theme;
        //var_dump($twig_vars['theme']);
    }

//// ==== THIS IS THE FUNCTION IN QUESTION ==== ////

    private function get_core_tpl() {

        foreach ($this->tpl_array as $value) {

            $pattern = array('/ /', '/_/');
            $name = preg_replace($pattern, '_', $value);
            $core[$name] = CORE_TPL . $value . '.html';
        }
        return $core;
    }

    private function get_tpl() {

        foreach ($this->tpl_array as $value) {

            $pattern = array('/ /', '/_/');
            $name = preg_replace($pattern, '_', $value);
            $tpl[$name] = 'tpl/' . $value . '.html';
            $page_tpl = $this->theme . '/tpl/' . $this->tpl_name . '-' . $value . '.html';

            if (file_exists($page_tpl))
                $tpl[$name] = '/tpl/' . $this->tpl_name . '-' . $value . '.html';
        }
        return $tpl;
    }

    private function get_theme_content() {
        $content = $this->get_files($this->theme . '/content', '.md');
        $content_data = array();

        if (empty($content))
            return;

        foreach ($content as $key) {
            $file = $this->theme . '/content/' . $key . '.md';
            $pattern = array('/ /', '/-/');
            $title = preg_replace($pattern, '_', strtolower($key));
            $data = file_get_contents($file);
            $content_data[$title] = \Michelf\MarkdownExtra::defaultTransform($data);
        }
        return $content_data;
    }

    private function get_views() {

        $view_dir = $this->theme . '/tpl/views';
        $views = $this->get_files($view_dir);

        if (empty($views))
            return;

        $pattern = array('/ /', '/-/');

        foreach ($views as $key) {
            $name = preg_replace($pattern, '_', $key);
            $view[$name] = 'tpl/views/' . $key . '.html';

            if (file_exists($this->theme . '/tpl/' . $this->tpl_name . '-' . $key . '.html'))
                $view[$name] = 'tpl/views/' . $this->tpl_name . '-' . $key . '.html';
        }

        if (!isset($view))
            return array(0);

        return $view;
    }

    // scrive.php lib
    private function get_files($directory, $ext = '.html') {

        if (!is_dir($directory))
            return false;

        $array_items = array();

        if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

                $file = $directory . "/" . $file;
                if (!$ext || strstr($file, $ext))
                $array_items[] = basename($file, $ext);
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
        return $array_items;
    }
} ?>
```

**Any help will be greatly appreciated!** Thnx

Comment: Is this a `symfony2` project? Doesn't look like to me. How come did you tag it with `symfony2` ?

Comment: Sorry, It isn't and think I got click happy - LOL _ I removed the tag.